# Raw processing grainy under Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: photo-management, photo

I try to convert Raw files to jpgs in Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit). I used UFraw, Rawtherapee and Darktable. All 3 converters seem to have problems since there are "hot pixels" (black dots in the resulting image) and the result in general is quite grainy. Even if i adjust the noise-reduction settings, I can't get satisfying results. Is this a bug of Ubuntu or does anybody have an answer?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Darktable as well as UFWRAW for a long while and have even contributed to journals with pictures done with Darktable, I have never come across this issue so far. Have you tried installing the latest version from their respective PPAs.

Comment: Well thats strange, i do have this strange bug